# Basic question I know but what is the different between this dropdown to select with up/down icons rather than a dropdown with a chevron?

Tags: icons, dropdown, selection, drop-down-list, fields

I have seen this a few times and never really gave it much thought. Why does it have an up and down arrows or how does it behave differently than a regular dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apple calls these things [pop-up buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/pop-up-buttons), as opposed to [pull-down buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/pull-down-buttons). They say:

> Use a pop-up button to present a flat list of mutually exclusive options or states. A pop-up button helps people make a choice that affects their content or the surrounding view. Use a pull-down button instead if you need to:
>
> - Offer a list of actions
> - Let people select multiple items
> - Include a submenu

Evidently, that's not what's going on in your screenshot though.

Stepping back from any concrete design guidelines, I'd say that a dropdown indicates that the options will appear below, whereas this indicates that options may appear above and below, or, in the case that this field actually is a text input field, that clicking the up/down part will expand the field into a multi-line textbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in this instance here I need a way to move the options up or down. Would I use the pop-up button and habr move up and move down options. Or click on the arrow for up and down?

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pwdr4qqvb8tom50ud7upo/up-and-down.png?rlkey=tw8kdfbjbncxg1m08f9z1lp54&dl=0